# unexpected sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Still new to Rails, but I have an issue where I am updating two models `enabled_reward` and `child` within the `enabled_rewards_controller` and it is signing out the child who is the `current_user`.

Can anyone offer some help? I don't know if something is happening to the cookie or the `remember_token` is being removed in the `update_attribute` call.  I don't have anything involving the `child` in the view, so I ruled that out.

Thanks in advance

Here is the `enabled_rewards_controller` update method:

```
def update
  @enabled_reward = EnabledReward.find(params[:id])

  if @enabled_reward.update_attributes(params[:enabled_reward])
    if @enabled_reward.redeemed
      @enabled_reward.child.update_attribute(:points,
        @enabled_reward.child.points - @enabled_reward.points)

      redirect_to @enabled_reward.child
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the rspec test:

```
before do
  sign_in child
  visit child_path(child)
end

describe "redeeming reward" do
  before { click_button "Redeem" }

  it "should still have the child signed in" do
    should_not have_link('Sign in') # fails
  end
end
```

Error message:

```
 Failure/Error: should_not have_link('Sign in')
   expected link "Sign in" not to return anything
 # ./spec/requests/child_pages_spec.rb:284:in `block (4 levels) 
   in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: please post failure message

Comment: It seems that updating @enabled_reward with `@enabled_reward.update_attributes(params[:enabled_reward])` rewrites `@enabled_reward.child` with new one with another id.

Comment: Does `update_attribute` still save the child model? Because I have `before_save :create_remember_token` in my child model which could be creating a new `remember_token` when I call `update_attribute`

Comment: ^ Perhaps maybe not do that in a `before_save`?

Comment: Make sure your form is passing the CSRF token properly. If it is missing, Rails will clear the session hash, which can play havoc with your "is the user logged in?" logic.